# NSFetchRequest on to-many-relationship excluding some objects does not work as expected

Tags: iphone, core-data

i struggling around NSFetchRequest these days. 
My data model look like this:

`Post <->> Category`

Now i need a fetch request to get all posts where the category.name attribute is not "xxx".
Looking at the documentation for NSFetchRequest is should be:

`NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NONE category.name == %@", categoryName]`

But this results in an empty list (the request is used by NSFetchedResultsController in an UITableView.

The docs say:

> NONE
>   Specifies none of the elements in the following expression. For example, NONE children.age < 18. This is logically equivalent to NOT (ANY ...).

If i invert my predicate to

`NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY category.name == %@", categoryName]`

the list contains exactly the objects i want to be excluded from that list.

What am i missing here?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The predicate form you have is correct.

The simplest explanation is that you have no objects that match the "@"NONE category.name == %@" predicate. That would explain why the inverse works.

I suggest that you:

1. Log the predicate with NSLog and see what the predicate actually is each time
2. Fetch all `Post` objects compare the count of objects returned with the count of objects returned by the "ANY" predicate. If they are the same then...
3. ...log the `category.name` values to see if any of them do match the "NONE" predicate.

I think that should allow you to find the problem.